# Converting sql statement to lambda to be used in razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

i have this select statment from web forms project and i want to convert it so i can use in my mvc project to be displayed in my dropdown lists in a razor page

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="Sections" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnection %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT e.DisplayName,  e.ID , e.GUID
                FROM Table1 e
                INNER JOIN RootTables re
                ON e.ID = re.Table1ID
                AND re.ChairID = 1">
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

i am thinking it starts like : `var sCommand = (from e in Table1....);`

Comment: Just fyi waht you're asking for is an equivalent LINQ to SQL statement. A lambda expression is only the `x => x ...` piece of a LINQ expression. It's really just an anonymous function you're passing into the query function (select, where, ect).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty straight forward. The query should be something like this:

```
var results = 
    from e in db.Table1
    join re in db.RootTables re
    on e.ID equals re.Table1ID
    where re.ChairID == 1
    select new { e.DisplayName, e.ID, e.GUID };
```

Or in fluent syntax:

```
var results = 
    db.Table1.Join(db.RootTables, 
        e => new { e.ID, ChairID = 1 }, 
        re => new { ID = re.Table1ID, re.ChairID },
        (e, re) => new { e.DisplayName, e.ID, e.GUID });
```

If you have set up your navigation properties appropriately, it gets even easier:

```
var results = 
    from e in db.Table1
    where e.RootTables.Any(re => re.ChairID == 1)
    select new { e.DisplayName, e.ID, e.GUID };
```

Or in fluent syntax:

```
var results = db.Table1.Where(e => e.RootTables.Any(re => re.ChairID == 1))
                       .Select(e => new { e.DisplayName, e.ID, e.GUID });
```

Comment: This is correct, but only if the data is not being accessed via Entity Framework, or any other ORM, which is usually not the case. If Entity Framework is used the join won't be needed.

Comment: @ataravati writing the join doesn't make it any less correct. If you're using an ORM the LINQ provider infers the join. A join is required and will be in the produced SQL either way.

Comment: @ataravati It would still work with EF / any other ORM, but you're right that if there are appropriate navigation properties a join is not necessary. I've provided an alternate version that would work in that case.

Comment: thanks this is great i am in the process of trying it out and since yes my project is not using entityframe work i will go with the last snippet. this will be used to populate to a dropdown list and i will write another linq to sql for another dropdown list but it will populate depending on the first dropdown list selected item. Do i handle that her in the sql or in the controller?

Comment: Also how should i return the results? List or IQueryable

Comment: @Masriyah Generally, you want to perform all your database queries (via Linq-to-Sql or any other method) in your controller, and just pass the results to your view. I'd personally use `AsEnumerable` and return it to your view as an `IEnumerable<T>`. Of course this is an anonymous type so you might have either create a `ViewModel` type to encapsulate the results or use some other trick to pass it to the view (generics, dynamic, another anonymous type, etc.)

Comment: i actually cannot add linq-to-sql in my controller and therefore i am creating this in a service layer in which i will access from my controller. I am just not sure how to return the results as a list or what i am using my model which returns name, id, guid. I will update my post. or create a new thread?

Comment: @Masriyah It's generally bad practice to have your views doing any database access. That should be hidden behind controllers or some other layers. How you do that depends a lot on how your project is structured and what code you've written so far. I'd recommend creating a new question for that, since this question was specifically about converting this one Linq query and your new question has more to do with your overall code structure.

Comment: thanks, yes i do access database in a different layer no the view. I will create a new post. thanks for the help i really appreciate it and any future help as well.